# Cambio de contraseña usando un archivo txt como base de datos (Java)

Tags: java, contraseña, modificaciones

Soy alguien nuevo en Java que, para un proyecto de mi Universidad, me pidieron crear un login y registro con ususario y contraseña, el cual se guarden los datos en un archivo .txt y que la contraseña sea modificable.

El login y el registro funcionan perfectmente, pero el de modificiar la contraseña hace que a la hora de modificar dicha contraseña, esta borre usuarios anteriores y reescribe solo un usuario, el cual es el que se le cambió la contraseña.

Este es el código para modificar la contraseña:

```java
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Scanner;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

...
private void verifUsuarioActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                             
        // TODO add your handling code here:
}                                            

private void confirmarContraActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                                
    // TODO add your handling code here:
    String usuario = verifUsuario.getText();
    String contra_actual = contraActual.getText();
    String contra_nueva = contraNueva.getText();
        
    try {
        File archivo = new File("datosUsuariosYContras.txt");
        Scanner escanear = new Scanner(archivo);
        escanear.useDelimiter("[,\n]");
            
        while(escanear.hasNext()) {
            String usuarioScan = escanear.next();
            String contraActualScan = escanear.next();

            if(usuario.equals(usuarioScan.trim()) && contra_actual.equals(contraActualScan.trim())){
                String str = usuario + "," + contra_actual;
                String str2 = str;
                String str3 = str2.replaceAll(str, "");
                PrintWriter imprimir = new PrintWriter(archivo);
                imprimir.println(str3 + usuario + "," + contra_nueva);
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Se modificó la contraseña exitosamente");
                imprimir.close();
                Mainpage inicio = new Mainpage();
                inicio.setVisible(true);
                this.dispose();
            }
            else {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "No se a podido modificar la contraseña");
            }
        }
    }
        
    catch (Exception e) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "No se a podido modificar la contraseña");
    }
}
```

Este es el código para el registro, por si algo sirve:

```
private void registrarseButtnActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                                 
    // TODO add your handling code here:
    String usuarioRegistrado = regUsuaTxtField.getText();
    String contraRegistrado = contraPsswrdField.getText();
        
    try {
        FileOutputStream archivo = new FileOutputStream("datosUsuariosYContras.txt", true);
        PrintWriter imprimir = new PrintWriter(archivo);
            
        imprimir.println(usuarioRegistrado + "," + contraRegistrado);
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Se ha registrado exitosamente");
        imprimir.close();
            
        Login login2 = new Login();
        login2.setVisible(true);
        this.dispose();
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
            
    }
}
```

Adjunto imágenes de lo que pasa antes y después de modificar la contraseña

[image: Antes:]

[image: Después:]

Gracias por la ayuda! :D

Comment: El código funciona bien, hace exactamente lo que tú le has indicado que haga. Si no quieres que te lo "borre" todo... no puedes pedirle al `PrintWriter` que escriba un archivo solo pasándole el usuario actual. Necesitarás imprimirlos todos otra vez si quieres guardar el archivo así. El objeto `PrintWriter` no permite *modificar* una línea, solo imprimir empezando por arriba y añadir líneas hacia abajo.. en este caso tendrás que hacer un bucle imprimiendo otra vez todos los usuarios y cuando llegues al que estás modificando, ponerle la contraseña nueva y seguir con los demás.

Comment: en vez de  `imprimir.println` por que no usas  `imprimir.append`?

Comment: @RuslanLópez como podria usar el `append` en este caso en particular?

Comment: @Benito-B voy a intentar usar esa solucion, gracias